# Integration of Stripe into Android Flutter app and an error in MainActivity.kt

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I'm trying to add Stripe Payment to my Android Flutter app using flutter_stripe: ^9.5.0+1 and flutter_dotenv: ^5.1.0.

I followed the instructions; the issue I'm experiencing is in the file 'MainActivity.kt'. I was told to change:

```
"class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() "
```

to:

```
"class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity()"
```

The issue is that 'androidx', 'embedding', 'FlutterFragmentActivity' and 'FlutterActivity' are shown as Unresolved reference (highlighted in red).

The app builds, however, when I try to use the Stripe module it states that I should inherit from 'FlutterFragmentActivity' despite the change I've made, so it seems that the file is not building and it's defaulting to 'FlutterActivity'?

I've tried everything I can find online and on ChatGBT, such as flutter clean, pub get, upgrade. I've upgraded flutter and Android Studio to the latest versions. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the code of the class where you made the changes you described?

Comment: Looks related to https://docs.page/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/troubleshooting#use-flutterfragmentactivity-instead-of-fluteractivity-as-mainactivity

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you skipped to import FlutterFragmentActivity

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
```